# Can I have two different sources pass data to an array adapter?

Tags: android, arrays, input, adapter

I am trying to add data from two different sources to an array adapter. One source is from a spinner containing hard coded strings, the other is to allow the user to create their own string to pass to the array (via the adapter). Here is my code below. It appears to me that the array adapter can only except one data source according to the arguments that can be passed to it.......ie

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
(this, R.array.alarmList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
```

Here I can only guess that the actual string input is gathered from......... android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
Do I need to use another array adapter or is there a way to add my string variable to the adaoter as well as the item the user has chosen from the spinner? I've done some research here but drawing a blank!!Many thanks. Here's my code which tries to enter strings to adapter..........

```
public class NewAlarm extends Activity {

Spinner alarms;
//private Button b =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddCustom);
final EditText et =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newalarm);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.alarmList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    //et.setText("name");
    alarms = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbAlarms);
    alarms.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addAlarm(View view) {
    MainMenu.alarmList.add(new Alarm(alarms.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added " +      alarms.getSelectedItem().toString() + " alarm.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    NewAlarm.this.finish();
}

public void addCustomAlarm (View view){

    MainMenu.alarmList.add(new Alarm(et.getText().toString())); 
}

}
```

And here's my array adapter code............

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_item, null);
      }
```

Thanks guys!!

```
      // Get a handle on the UI controls
      TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlarmName);
      final TextView timeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeStamp);
      // if the value of the timestamp from the alarm at the position selected is not a null value then set the text label to the alarm timestamp value
      if (MainMenu.alarmList.get(position).getTimeStamp() != null)
          {
            timeStamp.setText(MainMenu.alarmList.get(position).getTimeStamp().toString());
          }
      // Set the alarm name 
      name.setText(listItems.get(position).getName());
      // Get a handle on the button
      Button btnCheckNow = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckNow);

      btnCheckNow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {
              // Set the timestamp of the alarm object at the selected position
              MainMenu.alarmList.get(position).setTimeStamp();
              // Set the timestamp label 
              timeStamp.setText(MainMenu.alarmList.get(position).getTimeStamp().toString());
             }
      });
      return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()`, import the array and add the string before creating the adapter :

```
CharSequence[] array = Arrays.asList(
        getResources().getTextArray(R.array.alarmList));
List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(array);

list.add("custom string");

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```